# Continuous warnings in Kafka server.log

Tags: apache-kafka

i started zookeeper and Kafka server in Linux machine. Both servers are started successfully. After that i created a "test" Topic. Everything working fine using console producer and console consumer. But when i try to send an event from a remote machine to Kafka server, it is failing. After some investigation i added the below configuration in server.properties

listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://xx.xx.xx.xx:9092

Then i got below continues Warning in Kafka logs

[2018-05-25 14:48:27,685] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

But exceptions in controller.log

[2018-05-25 14:48:27,583] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker xx.xx.xx.xx:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.Req
uestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:70)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:271)
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:225)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:82)

Please help to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: try with `PLAINTEXT://:9092` or `PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`

Comment: it is not working